# Open lightning component from Opportunity Button, Link and action

Tags: lightning-aura-components

URLFOR is not working with new URL(with lightning in place of one/one.app#/) in Button, link and Action. I am unable to find solution for this.

Working with old url one/one.app#

```
{!IF(ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.StageName, 'Staging') , '/apex/ErrorPage',  URLFOR(' one/one.app#/n/test_component')
)}
```

But this URL is not working once you enable Critical update for new URL. 'one/one.app#' should be replace with 'lightning'

```
{!IF(ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.StageName, 'Staging') , '/apex/ErrorPage',  URLFOR('lightning/n/test_component)
)}
```

Comment: I noticed that you typed `lighting`, not `lightning`. Was that your problem? Also, you shouldn't have had a space in there.